# How can I reset the value of a string variable?

Tags: java, string, memory

Hey guys,
I'm trying to make a digital version of this Simon says game, and I can't get the path entered from the player to save correctly.
Every color corresponds to a number, so Green = 0, Red = 1, Yellow = 2, and Yellow = 3.
The problem is that the *playerPath* is never resetting, so it will just add the current entered path to the path of last round, making it seem incorrect when compared to the original *turnPath* which is just a substring of the *fullPath*.
I attached all of the code below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Simon implements ActionListener {  
    static JFrame f = new JFrame();  
    static JButton greenButton = new JButton("Green");  
    static JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");  
    static JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");  
    static JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");  
    static String playerPath = "";
    static int turn = 1;
    static int lostGame = 0;
    static Random rand = new Random();
    static String fullPath = ""; 
    static String turnPath;
    
    Simon() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              int maxIndex = 4;
              int randomIndex = rand.nextInt(maxIndex);
              fullPath = fullPath + randomIndex;
            }       
            
            turnPath =  fullPath.substring(0,turn);
            
 
        prepareGUI();
        buttonProperties();
        
    }
    
public void prepareGUI() {
    f.setSize(415,435);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);  
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void buttonProperties() {
    greenButton.setBounds(0,0,200,200);  
    redButton.setBounds(200,0,200,200);  
    yellowButton.setBounds(0,200,200,200);  
    blueButton.setBounds(200,200,200,200);  
 
    greenButton.setBackground(Color.black); 
    redButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    yellowButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    blueButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    
    greenButton.setOpaque(true);
    redButton.setOpaque(true);
    yellowButton.setOpaque(true);
    blueButton.setOpaque(true);
    
    greenButton.setForeground(Color.green); 
    redButton.setForeground(Color.red);
    yellowButton.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    blueButton.setForeground(Color.blue);
 
    f.add(greenButton);  
    f.add(redButton);  
    f.add(yellowButton);  
    f.add(blueButton);  
    
    greenButton.addActionListener(this);
    redButton.addActionListener(this);
    yellowButton.addActionListener(this);
    blueButton.addActionListener(this);
    
    greenButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            greenButton.setBackground(Color.green);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            greenButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        }

    });
    
    redButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            redButton.setBackground(Color.red);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            redButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        }

    });

    yellowButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            yellowButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            yellowButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        }

    });
    
    blueButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            blueButton.setBackground(Color.blue);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            blueButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Recording user input

    
        if (e.getActionCommand().matches("Green")) {
            
            playerPath += "0";
            
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().matches("Red")) {
            
            playerPath += "1";
            
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().matches("Yellow")) {
            
            playerPath += "2";
            
        }
        else if (e.getActionCommand().matches("Blue")) {
            
            playerPath += "3";
            
        }
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {  
    while (lostGame < 1) {
        
    lightButtons();
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 + (1000*turn));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    if (playerPath.equals(turnPath)) {
        playerPath = "";
        turn++; 
    }
        
    else if (!(playerPath.equals(turnPath))) {

        lostGame += 1;
        System.out.println(playerPath);
        System.out.println(turnPath);
        System.out.println("GAME OVER" + '\n' + "Your Score: " + (turn-1));
    }
    
    }
}

public static void lightButtons() {
    new Simon();
       
    
    for (int i = 0; i < turnPath.length(); i++) { // iterates through string based on turn number
        if (turnPath.charAt(i) == '0') {                    
      
        greenButton.setBackground(Color.green);         //* "Flashes" a color at appropriate box
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
          greenButton.setBackground(Color.black);       //*
          try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        else if (turnPath.charAt(i) == '1') {
          redButton.setBackground(Color.red);           //*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            redButton.setBackground(Color.black);       //*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        else if (turnPath.charAt(i) == '2') {
          yellowButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);     //*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            yellowButton.setBackground(Color.black);    //*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        else if (turnPath.charAt(i) == '3') {
          blueButton.setBackground(Color.blue);         //*
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
            blueButton.setBackground(Color.black);      //* 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            
        }
        
        
      }
    
}
} ```
````

Comment: just assign it a (default) value, how else?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a String variable by writing `playerPath = "";`

Comment: Thanks, but I already did that here: '''if (playerPath.equals(turnPath)) {
        playerPath = "";
        turn++; 
    } ''' and it isn't working